# How can I make my pc hibernate if pc battery level drops 18%?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

I get my battery level via -

```
WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining
```

and the output is =>
EstimatedChargeRemaining
100

Also, I can hibernate my pc with command like,

```
shutdown /h
```

So, how come I write a script such that when the battery level drops below 20%, it just hibernate my pc, 
 how do I make it happen? Also, when I power on it again it won't just hibernate again, I mean to only function it once, and activate the function again when the battery level goes above 21%, so that its a feasible service. Any help would be really worth... Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I know about these things in windows as suggested, but I wanted to create something that would hibernate automatically even if the laptop is tried to start by someone else so, the opened processes or other running tasks won't run out/ or crash abruptly. So finally I made this program in node, and made a bat file, with

```
node Autohibernate.js
```

and hence the node program will be executed by this. And finally to make it run in hidden mode, and even if the pc is restarted, I made a vbscript program that does this. And it is like this-

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\autohibernate.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

So, finally there is the node program, i.e., autohibernate.js shown below-

```
const { exec, spawn } = require("child_process");
let current;
let critical = 18; // Battery level at which hibernates.
let repeatAfterActionFired = 1; //In minutes.
let generalCheckTimer = 3; // Check after every this time(in second).

async function somelife() {
  exec("WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    current = stdout.slice(29);
    console.log("battery-", current);
    if (current > critical) {
      checkAndHibernate();
    } else {
      console.log(
        `Hibernation Fired, Next checkAndHibernate after ${repeatAfterActionFired} minutes.`
      );
      setTimeout(() => {
        checkAndHibernate();
      }, repeatAfterActionFired * 60 * 1_000);

      exec("shutdown /h");
      // exec()
    }
  });
}
const checkAndHibernate = () =>
  setTimeout(() => {
    somelife();
  }, generalCheckTimer * 1_000);
checkAndHibernate();
```

Thanks, Stackoverflow.